# Python Pandas - Cumulative time series data, calculate change?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

I'm pulling data from an API at intervals, each item I pull has a "start date" (for the ad campaign, t1) and the next points will be an increasing t2 value (now). It's for a learning project I'm doing, as I'm relatively new to data science.

The values, such as revenue, cost, clicks, conversions etc. are cumulative. To find the change from one datapoint to the next, I'd have to subtract n - (n-1), as n contains the data from (n-1).

I pull the data into a dataframe using (the database is sqlite for now):

```
SQL = """SELECT 
MAX(a.t2) as "Snapshot time",
a.volid AS "Camp ID", 
a.tsid AS "TS ID", 
a.placement as "Source ID", 
a.clicks AS "Clicks tracker", 
a.visits AS "Visits tracker", 
a.conversions AS "Conversion", 
a.revenue AS "Revenue USD", 
b.cost AS "Cost USD" ,
b.clicks AS "ts Clicks",
from tracker a JOIN ts b ON a.placement = b.placement AND a.tsid = 
b.campaignid AND a.t2 = b.t2
GROUP BY a.voli, a.tsid, a.placement"""

df = pd.read_sql_query(SQL, conn)
df_t2['snapshot'] = pd.to_datetime(df_t2['snapshot'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')

# Generate time value for the second sql query, for n-x
t1 = df_t2['snapshot'].max() - dt.timedelta(hours=offset)
t1 = t1.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ')
```

This gives me the latest snapshot (t0--tn). My initial thought was to make a similar dataframe for (t0-t(n-1)) and subtract them, which is there the t1 variable came into the picture in the code above.

But I tried this and can't get it to work. I also tested to handle it like a time series in Pandas, but I'm not sure if my data structure works for that.

The expected behavior would be to get a dataframe only consisting of data for tn-t(n-1). Even better if it would be possible to generate *all* the n-(n-1) for the entire series, so each record would be an increment and not a cumulative value.

Any input would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you post a sample of df?

Comment: Hi, yes

Here's an example output:

https://pastebin.com/GgWJYFPk